I can't get a window to appear
I am a newbie programmer trying to learn. I'm trying to create a simple video game, and so I am following the guide from a guy on YouTube.
However, I've run into an issue where, even though I compile the code and create an .exe file, when I run that .exe file nothing happens. I tried manipulating the code to get something to happen, but yet nothing.
I tried changing the CreateWindowExW() function and manipulating the values to get something to appear, yet no progress. There are no syntax errors, everything compiles cleanly, and I can make an executable. However, when I compile it nothing works. I'm assuming I used a function wrong, but I'm not sure since ChatGPT told me my code should work.
#include <windows.h>

bool running = true;

void*  buffer_memory;
int buffer_width;
int buffer_height;
BITMAPINFO buffer_bitmap_info;
// this controls the memory assigned and allows for good memory allocation
LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  LRESULT result =0;
  
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
      running = false;
      break;
    
    case WM_SIZE: {
      RECT rect;
      GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
      buffer_width = rect.right - rect.left;
      buffer_height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

      int buffer_size = buffer_width*buffer_height *sizeof(unsigned int);
      if(buffer_memory) VirtualFree(buffer_memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
      buffer_memory = VirtualAlloc(0, buffer_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = buffer_width;
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = buffer_height;
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
      buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    }
      break;
    default: {
      result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Creating a typedef function so I can compile without having to link to a library
typedef int (WINAPI* StretchDIBitsFunc)(HDC, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const VOID*, const BITMAPINFO*, UINT, DWORD);

int WinMain(HINSTANCE  hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
  //Create Window Class
  WNDCLASS window_class ={};
  window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  const wchar_t* WindowName = L"Game Window Class";
  LPCWSTR GameName = L"Ping Pong";
 //window_class.lpszClassName = GameName;
  window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;


  // Register Class
  RegisterClass(&window_class);

  // Create Window
  HWND window = CreateWindowExW(0,WindowName, GameName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
  HDC hdc = GetDC(window);
  StretchDIBitsFunc StretchDIBits = reinterpret_cast<StretchDIBitsFunc>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "StretchDIBits"));

  // Load StretchDIBits function dynamically(so I dont have to link it to a library and it compiles)

  while(running) {
      // Input
      MSG message;
      while(PeekMessage(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);

      }  
      // Simulate
      unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)buffer_memory;
      for (int i = 0; i < buffer_height; i++) {
          for (int z = 0; z < buffer_width; z++) {
              *pixel++ = 0xff5500;
          }           
      }

      // Render 
      if(StretchDIBits){ 
          StretchDIBits(hdc,0,0, buffer_width, buffer_height, 0, 0, buffer_width, buffer_height, buffer_memory, &buffer_bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
      }
  }
  return 0;
}


Looks like you may be using C/C++, you may find you get better results on this question if you update the tags to include your programming language.

Don't skip assigning window_class.lpszClassName.  The code reversed the 2nd and 3rd arguments to CreateWindowEx().  You avoid such mistakes by picking good identifier names.  Further improve the code by checking for return values of winapi calls, at minimum with an assert.

Start by adding error handling on every single API call that reports errors. You'll find the issue quickly. The documentation for each API call explains how values are returned and what the returned values mean.

Also: The dangers of filtering window messages.


I've made a couple of changes to the posted code. Give it a try -
The first two points are as @HansPassant said.
I use the memory buffer_size as:
stride = ((((biWidth * biBitCount) + 31) & ~31) >> 3);
biSizeImage = abs(biHeight) * stride;

See Calculating Surface Stride for more information.
The fourth point is the reference to StretchDIBits.
#include <windows.h>

bool running = true;

void* buffer_memory;
int buffer_width;
int buffer_height;
BITMAPINFO buffer_bitmap_info;
// this controls the memory assigned and allows for good memory allocation
LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    LRESULT result = 0;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        running = false;
        break;

    case WM_SIZE: {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        buffer_width = rect.right - rect.left;
        buffer_height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        //int buffer_size = buffer_width * buffer_height * sizeof(unsigned int); 3
        int buffer_size = ((buffer_width * 32 + 31) / 32) * 4 * buffer_height;

        if (buffer_memory) VirtualFree(buffer_memory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        buffer_memory = VirtualAlloc(0, buffer_size, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader);
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = buffer_width;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = buffer_height;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
        buffer_bitmap_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    }
                break;
    default: {
        result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    }

    return result;
}

// Creating a typedef function so I can compile without having to link to a library
typedef int (WINAPI* StretchDIBitsFunc)(HDC, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, const VOID*, const BITMAPINFO*, UINT, DWORD);

int WinMain(HINSTANCE  hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    //Create Window Class
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    const wchar_t* WindowName = L"Game Window Class";
    LPCWSTR GameName = L"Ping Pong";
    window_class.lpszClassName = GameName;//1
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;


    // Register Class
    RegisterClass(&window_class);

    // Create Window
    //HWND window = CreateWindowExW(0, WindowName, GameName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);2
    HWND window = CreateWindowExW(0, GameName, WindowName, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    HDC hdc = GetDC(window);
    //StretchDIBitsFunc StretchDIBits = reinterpret_cast<StretchDIBitsFunc>(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "StretchDIBits"));

    // Load StretchDIBits function dynamically(so I dont have to link it to a library and it compiles)

    while (running) {
        // Input
        MSG message;
        while (PeekMessage(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);

        }
        // Simulate
        unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)buffer_memory;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer_height; i++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < buffer_width; z++) {
                *pixel++ = 0xff5500;
            }
        }

        // Render 4
        //if (StretchDIBits) {
            StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, buffer_width, buffer_height, 0, 0, buffer_width, buffer_height, buffer_memory, &buffer_bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
        //}
    }
    return 0;
}

